# React Native-Redux Error: undefined is not an object(evaluating

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have got the error message

> "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'CategoryAction2.default.categoryView')" on executing the below code,

ConfigureStore.js:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

var middlewares = applyMiddleware(thunk);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(reducers, initialState, middlewares);
}
```

CategoryContainer.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import stores from '../stores/ConfigureStore';
import CategoryAction from '../actions/CategoryAction';

stores.dispatch(CategoryAction.categoryView());

class CategoryContainer extends Component {
}
```

CategoryAction.js

```
import * as actionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import AppConstants from '../constants/AppConstants';

export function categoryView() {
  const categories = ['Health', 'Built-in'];
  return {
      type: "CATEGORY_VIEW",
      categories: categories
  };
}
```

CategoryReducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
  categories:[],
}

export default function categoryReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CATEGORY_VIEW:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
              categories: action.categories
            });
    }
}
```

The below line in CategoryContainer.js raises the error message,
stores.dispatch(CategoryAction.categoryView());

Kindly assist to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CategoryContainer.js, you need to import the specific member (or all members) of CategoryActions.js. Should be one of the two options below:

```
import * as CategoryAction from '../actions/CategoryAction';

// or

import { categoryView } from '../actions/CategoryAction';
stores.dispatch(categoryView());
```